# Bread is bread but

Tags: riddle, knowledge, wordplay, language

> Bread is bread but what bread you can't eat?
> Bridges are bridges but what bridge doesn't connect two landmasses?
> Paper is paper but what paper you can't write on?
> Candies are candies but what candy you can't eat?

---

This riddle has four answers (one word for each line). These words do not have any connection with each other but there is a specific solving pattern for this riddle. You aren't required to guess words that fit the lines and work through the riddle. Once the pattern is recognized, the riddle can be solved easily.

---

Hint 1:

> It's a [wordplay](/questions/tagged/wordplay)

Hint 2:

> I have used the tag [language](/questions/tagged/language). So knowledge of a specific non-English language will prove helpful.

Hint 3:

> This language is both native and primary to the people living in their country. That means English is not the official language in this country.

Hint 4:

> This language is spoken in an Asian country

Final hint:

Comment: Hello Nilay Ghosh. Are these 4 seperate words connected to each other? If not, are these 4 separate riddles? The answers seem to say so.

Comment: @DrD these are 4 separate words but the solving pattern for each words is same. Once you recognise the pattern, the solution becomes easy. I will include 3 more hints later.

Comment: Your comment about same solving pattern should probably be incorporated into the puzzle as it rules out the attempts to simply find four things that fit your criteria. Otherwise this looks to be on the way to getting closed.

Comment: @Amoz Thank you for the comment. I should have included the details in the body at the start. I guess it is fine now.

Answer (score 8):

I believe that the tag you deliberately omitted is

> **Science** (In particular, Electrical Engineering)

*Bread is bread but what bread you can't eat?*

> [**Bread**board](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadboard)
>
>  [image]

*Bridges are bridges but what bridge doesn't connect two landmasses?*

> [Wheatstone **bridge**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wheatstone_bridge)
>
>  [image]

*Paper is paper but what paper you can't write on?*

> [High voltage power cable **paper**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrical_insulation_paper#High_voltage_power_cable_paper)
>
>  [image]

*Candies are candies but what candy you can't eat?*

> [**Candy** (the domestic appliance manufacturer)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Candy_(company))
>
>  [image]

Comment: Nice attempt but not the answer I am looking for.

Comment: Well I'm curious to see the correct answer then...

Answer (score 3):

As the tag [wordplay] is included in the description of the puzzle, I'll take a stab at it:

*Bread is bread but what bread you can't eat?*

> A secondary definition for bread (or dough) is money. To my current knowledge, eating money is ill-advised. (And inedible)

*Bridges are bridges but what bridge doesn't connect two landmasses?*

> I believe you are referring to bridge as in the card game.

*Paper is paper but what paper you can't write on?*

> Tissue paper??? Whenever I've tried to write on it, it tears apart.

*Candies are candies but what candy you can't eat?*

> This is a stretch, but *nose candy.* Nose candy is a slang meaning a drug that is snorted or ingested via the nose.

Comment: I was thinking similar for the first 3, but you beat me to it, last one I was thinking of rot13(rlr pnaql) but it's as much of a stretch as yours probably :p

Comment: Hint: Your profile name should be useful in solving this puzzle. rot13(Wbr Xree -> Wbxre. Pna lbh rfgnoyvfu n eryngvbafuvc?)

Answer (score 1):

I don't feel very confident because I was grasping at straws on the third one. The pattern I found is:

> the French word *fric*, an informal reference to money

Bread is bread but what bread you can't eat?

> *fric* might translate into dough or bread

Bridges are bridges but what bridge doesn't connect two landmasses?

> Trade and economic relationships are bridges that connect communities...?

Paper is paper but what paper you can't write on?

> *fric* might translate into paper or paper bills

Candies are candies but what candy you can't eat?

> *fric* might translate into lolly as in lollipop

Answer (score -2):

PARTIAL ANSWER

---

> Bread is bread but what bread you can't eat?

> Sourdough (sour dough)

> Bridges are bridges but what bridge doesn't connect two landmasses?

> The bridge in a ship. (the raised part of a ship on which the captain and other officers stand and from where they control the movement of the ship)

> Paper is paper but what paper you can't write on?

> Cant solve this.

> Candies are candies but what candy you can't eat?

> This ones a far one but.. Cotton Candy (cotton as in the plant fiber)

Comment: Nice attempt but not the correct answer.

Comment: Hint: One of your question post has an indirect relationship with my riddle. More specifically rot13(lbh unir hfrq n ynathntr nf n onfr va bar bs lbhe cbfg juvpu unf na vaqverpg eryngvba jvgu zl evqqyr. Gubhtu, zl nafjre vf abg va gur fnzr ynathntr nf lbhef.)